# Does frequent ping affect local network speed?

Tags: ping, performance-monitoring, network-monitoring, system-monitoring

(Sorry for my english)

Hi, I am about to set up a monitoring server and wanted to know if pinging the network devices could significantly affect the speed of the local network.
I want to ping every device on the network in an interval of less than 1 minute.
So, can it ping every 30 seconds without hightly decreasing local network speed or device's performances ?

Comment: As a side note: pinging servers is not representative of their state. I've seen many crashed servers that still respond to ping. It's better to scan the services that run on it.

Comment: Yes, I've seen that, that's why I'll use SNMP too, I'm just trying to see if a device responds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, such ping interval will not slow down anything: a 64 byte ping (and reply) every 30s means an average load of ~4 byte/sec, which is totally negligible even on ancient, half duplex 10 Mbit networks.

You would need an enormous number of monitored host to cause some slowdown on the network, with the monitor machine itself succumbing *much* sooner to the load caused by tracking them all.